# Django How to Load data to the initial base.html template

Tags: django, templates, radix

My initial template base.html must load menus with items dynamically loaded at the beginning. Is it possible? Some hints?

Comment: did you try to extend the base.html and change html code? it need view also

Comment: could you share your code so that it's easy to see & debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use template inheritance which is provided by Django. But in your case suppose you have two different templates with names `navbar.html` and `base.html` and you want to add `navbar.html` to beginning of your `base.html`. With Django tag (i.e. `{% include 'navbar.html' %}` ) you can include your `navbar.html` content in your `base.html`. Just like following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Try Django</title>
</head>
<body>
{% include 'navbar.html' %}
</body>
</html>
```

In other scenario if you want to add something to your `base.html` (for example `product_list.html`) you can use Django tag (i.e. `{% extends 'base.html' %}` ) in your destination template but do not forget to use `{% block content %}` and `{% endblock content %}` in your `base.html` (for example in the body tag of `base.html` and then use `{% block content %}` and `{% endblock content %}` in your destination template. Finally just add your codes between that block contents of yours. For more information check the following codes:
`base.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Try Django</title>
</head>
<body>
{% include 'navbar.html' %}
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

`product_list.html`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

{% for obj in object_list %}
    {{ obj.id }} - <a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}">{{ obj.name }}</a><br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

And if you need something else just go to [Django template docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/).